# Implementation of two Sliding Windows over a multivariate sequence of data in python

Tags: python, stream, time-series, sliding-window, data-preprocessing

I am trying to construct two sliding windows over a multivariate sequence of data (*m*n*). The first window should be fixed and the second one is rolling over the data samples. Both windows have the same size. I followed this post[distance calculations, FFT, Sliding window](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578015/speed-up-distance-calculations-fft-sliding-window) and built upon that. I am struggling to implement it. The python snippet of the code is below:

```
sliding_dist(data,window_size):
  window_size = 10
  n = len(data)
  dist = np.zeros(n)
  for i in range(n - window_size):
    fixed_window = data[i:window_size, :]
    rolling_window = data[i:i + window_size,:]
    ditance = np.linalg.norm(fixed_window - rolling_window)
    dist[i] = ditance
  return dist
```

My problem is how to fix the first window and keep the second on rolling over data sample *n*. Logically, I am not quite sure whether the implementation of **for loop** and indexes are correct or should I change them. Also, I have issue with the indexes I got an error about the shape: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (9,3) (10,3)`

**Edit:**

I just edited the code to take the fixed window out of the for loop. It solved the previous error `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (9,3) (10,3)` :

```
sliding_dist(data,window_size):
  window_size = 10
  n = len(data)
  dist = np.zeros(n)
  fixed_window = data[:window_size, :]
  for i in range(n - window_size):
    rolling_window = data[i:i + window_size,:]
    ditance = np.linalg.norm(fixed_window - rolling_window)
    dist[i] = ditance
  return dist
```

I am still not sure about whether the way I implemented the two sliding windows is correct or not? Please could anyone have some thoughts and help on this.

Comment: *"I am trying to construct two sliding windows over a sequence of data (m*n)"* But the question you linked has two sequences, one of length m, and one of length n. There is no sequence of length `m*n`.

Comment: What I meant was that a single sequence (not two) with m samples and n dimensions. In other words, running the sliding windows on multivariate sequence data.